# Svelte - Updating component render using a filter word received via an input box

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

So I have made a basic application using SvelteKit / TailwindCSS

In short it just pulls the popular movies from tmdb.org and renders them via a component

In the navigation, I am using a search box, where I can enter the filter text like a specific movie name and basis that the inputValue changes, which is even change unto the point of function inside the component.

Navigation.svelte has search box and the {#each} is in PopularMovies.svelte

But the DOM area is not changing

**index.svelte**

```
<script context='module'>
  export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch(
      'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=KEY_RECEIVED_FROM_TMDB'
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    if (res.ok) {
      return { props : { movieInfo: data.results} };
    }
  }
</script>

<script>
  import Navigation from "../components/Navigation.svelte";
  import PopularMovies from "../components/PopularMovies.svelte";
  export let movieInfo;
</script>

<div class="flex flex-col">
 
  <Navigation/>

  <div class='justify-center'>
    <PopularMovies {movieInfo}/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Inside src, I have created components folder and there, we have

**Navigations.svete**.

```
<script>
    import { filterMovies } from "./PopularMovies.svelte";
    let inputValue = '';
</script>

<div class="bg-gray-50 h-1/12 w-full shadow-lg py-4 mb-10">
    <nav class="flex mx-auto justify-between bg-gray-50 w-5/6">
        <p class="text-xl font-bold">The Movie DataBase</p>
        <div class="flex flex-row w-1/2 justify-end">
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Name" bind:value="{inputValue}"
                class="pl-4 py-1 mx-4 w-2/4 border rounded-full">
        <button class="border border-blue-900 text-black text-base font-semibold
                        px-8 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white"
                on:click={filterMovies(inputValue)} >
            Search</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**PopularMovies.svelte**

```
<script context='module'>
    let title = 'Morbius';
    export function filterMovies(name) {
        title = name;
    }
</script>
<script>
    import { Result } from "postcss";
    import { each } from "svelte/internal"
    import MovieCards from "./MovieCards.svelte";
    export let movieInfo = "";
</script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
    {title}
    {#each movieInfo as movie}
        {#if movie.title == title}
            <MovieCards {movie} />
        {/if}
    {/each}
</div>
```

**MovieCards**

```
<script>
    export let movie;
</script>


<div class="relative flex flex-col h-full m-4 w-1/12 
            rounded-md hover:border hover:border-gray-50 duration-100 cursor-pointer">
    
    <div class="absolute -inset-0.5 bg-gray-900 rounded-md opacity-50 blur-md"></div>

    <div class="relative bg-white rounded-md overflow-hidden">
        <div class="m-1 rounded-md overflow-hidden">
            <img src="{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w440_and_h660_face' + movie.backdrop_path}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="px-4 py-2">
            <p class="text-sm font-bold truncate pb-2">{movie.title}</p>
            <p class="text-xs font-light">{movie.release_date}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update the movie cards basis search text. At the moment I am trying exact match but later, I would also try to fuzzy match

I see from search box until he PopularMovies component, I managed to take the value but change is not updating the {#each} in DOM

Am new to Svelte, like I just started it last evening. Pardon my lack of knowledge, I searched a lot before writing here

Comment: I assume nothing changes because `let title = 'Morbius';` is inside the `<script context='module'>` In Svelte the values can be accessed from outside, but they are not reactive like in the normal script. See this REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/84f08ccb9fee4abbbc6d35ddc2cdb304?version=3.48.0 Not sure if there are differences in SvelteKit

Comment: @Corrl Thank you. Your solution helped me put together the working functionality

Answer (score 0):

Made changes as per the suggestion of @corrl

So Navigation component has a store value, which is changed using the binded value in the input text

And this store value is exported in PopularMovies component and used as filter

Below is the code change in both components

**Navigation.svelte**

```
<script context='module'>
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
    export let title = writable('title');
</script>
<script>
    let inputValue = '';
    $title = '';
    function filterMovies(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        $title = resp;
    }
</script>

<div class="bg-gray-50 h-1/12 w-full shadow-lg py-4 mb-10">
    <nav class="flex mx-auto justify-between bg-gray-50 w-5/6">
        <p class="text-xl font-bold">The Movie DataBase</p>
        <div class="flex flex-row w-1/2 justify-end">
        <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Name" bind:value="{inputValue}"
                class="pl-4 py-1 mx-4 w-2/4 border rounded-full">
        <button class="border border-blue-900 text-black text-base font-semibold
                        px-8 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white"
                on:click={filterMovies(inputValue)} >
            Search</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And in **PopularMovies.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { Result } from "postcss";
    import { each } from "svelte/internal"
    import MovieCards from "./MovieCards.svelte";
    import { title } from "./Navigation.svelte";
    export let movieInfo = "";
    function filter(query, data) {
        return query.match(data);
    }
</script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
    {#each movieInfo as movie}
        {#if filter(movie.title, $title)}
            <MovieCards {movie} />
        {:else if $title == ''}
            <MovieCards {movie} />
        {/if}
    {/each}
</div>
```